# Ansible playbook - regexp | unable to change data in brackets and quotes

Tags: ansible, filebeat, regexp-replace

I've been trying to finish up a playbook for deploying a new server. I'm struggling with changing data within brackets containing quotes via `lineinfile` and a regex:

```yaml
- name: "Configuring: filebeat agent - configuring output to logstash"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
    regexp: '#hosts: ["localhost:5044"]'
    line: 'hosts: ["elk.home:5044"]'
  tags: application
```

After the playbook is executed, the desired line:

```
#hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

is **not** updated to reflect:

```
hosts: ["elk.home:5044"]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

`#hosts: ["localhost:5044"]` is replaced with `hosts: ["elk.home:5044"]`

There are no errors generated. I've tried varying `"` and `'` along with escapes `\`, but I can't get the expression correct. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I could guess (could be wrong) that you are using the `lineinfile` module? But answers cannot be based on guesses. You'll need to update the question with relevant portions of your playbook, what is happening, and what you expect.

Comment: The `filebeat.yml` configuration file can contain `#hosts: ["localhost:5044"]` at many places. You could try a different `regexp` with `insertbefore` or `insertafter` options to target the exact setting. You could also consider the [replace module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/replace_module.html).

Comment: Also, `[` and `]` do have a meaning in a regex, they delimit a character class, if you want to match them as literal, you need to escape those two characters: `regexp: '#hosts: \["localhost:5044"\]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks seshadri_c and β.εηοιτ.βε!

I was able to reach a resolution with the following lines:

```
- name: "Configuring: filebeat agent - enabling logstash output hosts"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
    regexp: '#hosts: \["localhost:5044"\]'
    line: 'hosts: ["elk.home:5044"]'
  tags: 
    - configuration
    - application
    - filebeat
```

After completing the playbook, I had an issue with whitespace. I added two spaces that correctly modified the line

```
- name: "Configuring: filebeat agent - enabling logstash output hosts"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
    regexp: '#hosts: \["localhost:5044"\]'
    line: '  hosts: ["elk.home:5044"]'
  tags: 
    - configuration
    - application
    - filebeat
```